# Environment that doesn't allow blank lines

Tags: environments

Consider the command `\mpagetc` defined as

```
\newcommandx*\mpagetc[4][1=0.45,2=0.45]{\begin{minipage}{\textheight}%
\begin{minipage}[c]{#1 \textwidth}% 
#3
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{#2 \textwidth}% 
#4
\end{minipage}%
\end{minipage}}
```

I get the error `Paragraph ended before \\mpagec was complete` *only* when I have a blank line in the code,

```
\mpagetc{
blablabla

blablabla
}{ blablabla}
```

I have the same problems with other commands that does not allow blank lines. What is the problem with blank lines?

Answer (score 12):

Blank lines tantamount to `\par`; using the starred version `\newcommandx*` forbids `\par` inside the defined command. For "long" commands (i.e., admitting `\par`), you should use the un-starred version `\newcommandx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xargs}

\newcommandx\mpagetc[4][1=0.45,2=0.45]{\begin{minipage}{\textheight}%
\begin{minipage}[c]{#1 \textwidth}% 
#3
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{#2 \textwidth}% 
#4
\end{minipage}%
\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\mpagetc{a 

b}{c}

\end{document}
```

The same remark applies to standard (i.e., without `xargs`) `\newcommand` and `\newcommand*`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not strictly tied to `xargs`, I'd suggest `xparse` and a change of order in the optional arguments:

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mpagetc}{ O{0.45} +m O{0.45} +m }{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{#1\textwidth}
  #2
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[c]{#3\textwidth}
  #4
  \end{minipage}%
}
```

so that you can set the two factors independently of each other

```
\mpagetc{A}{B}

\mpagetc[0.3]{A}{B}

\mpagetc{A}[0.4]{B}

\mpagetc[0.3]{A}[0.4]{B}
```

By specifying the mandatory arguments with `+m` they are “long”.

Complete example.

```
\documentclass{article}

% the following three lines are just for the example
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mpagetc}{ O{0.45} +m O{0.45} +m }{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{#1\textwidth}
  #2
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[c]{#3\textwidth}
  #4
  \end{minipage}%
}


\begin{document}
\mpagetc{
  \scriptsize\lipsum[2]

  End.
}{
  \scriptsize\lipsum[4]

  End.
}

\mpagetc[0.3]{
  \scriptsize\lipsum[2]

  End.
}{
  \scriptsize\lipsum[4]

  End.
}

\mpagetc{
  \scriptsize\lipsum[2]

  End.
}[0.3]{
  \scriptsize\lipsum[4]

  End.
}

\mpagetc[0.3]{
  \scriptsize\lipsum[2]

  End.
}[0.5]{
  \scriptsize\lipsum[4]

  End.
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wow, I like this way!